# Search record in grid view

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

The read record is solved. I still have another problem the error message still remain there after user key in correct order id.

```
    query = "select FoodName, Qty, IngredientName, Quantity, OrderStatus 
             from tblorder, tblorderdetail, tblfood, tblcustomizefooddetail, tblcustomizeingredient, tblordercustomize 
             where tblOrder.OrderId = @OrderId and OrderStatus = @OrderStatus and tblorder.OrderId = tblorderdetail.OrderId and tblorderdetail.FoodId = tblfood.FoodId and tblorderdetail.OrderDetailId = tblordercustomize.OrderDetailId and tblfood.FoodId = tblcustomizefooddetail.FoodId and tblcustomizeingredient.IngredientId = tblcustomizefooddetail.IngredientId and tblordercustomize.IngredientId = tblcustomizeingredient.IngredientId"

    com = New MySqlCommand(query, conn)

    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderId", txtOrderId.Text)
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderStatus", "Pending")

    Dim sqladapter As New MySqlDataAdapter(com)
    sqladapter.Fill(dt)

    If dt.Rows.Count Then
        GridView1.DataSource = dt
        GridView1.DataBind()
    Else
        Label1.Text = "Order ID Doesn't Exist"
    End If
```

Comment: you are already reading the first record so you are leaving the first one out. Why not use the SqlDataAdapter and let it do all the hard work for you? Furthermore, I don't see you closing your connect but suspect this is just a snippet of code.

Comment: Can show some example? I'm new

Comment: You said "only read the first record" - this is because you do `dr.Read` - it reads one record. Then you do `dt.Load(dr)` - it reads starting with second record. Definitely use `sqldataadapter` since your goal is to get `datatable`. Go to MSDN for examples. Google for `.net sqldataadapter` and you will be there.

Answer (score 0):

Lets take your sample and modify it:

```
query = "select FoodName, Qty, IngredientName, Quantity, OrderStatus 
             from tblorder, tblorderdetail, tblfood, tblcustomizefooddetail, tblcustomizeingredient, tblordercustomize 
             where tblOrder.OrderId = @OrderId and OrderStatus = @OrderStatus and tblorder.OrderId = tblorderdetail.OrderId and tblorderdetail.FoodId = tblfood.FoodId and tblorderdetail.OrderDetailId = tblordercustomize.OrderDetailId and tblfood.FoodId = tblcustomizefooddetail.FoodId and tblcustomizeingredient.IngredientId = tblcustomizefooddetail.IngredientId and tblordercustomize.IngredientId = tblcustomizeingredient.IngredientId"

    com = New MySqlCommand(query, conn)

    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderId", txtOrderId.Text)
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderStatus", "Pending")

    Dim adapter as new SqlDataAdapter(com)
adapter.Fill(dt)

if adapter.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0
        GridView1.DataSource = adapter.Tables(0)
        GridView1.DataBind()
    Else
        Label1.Text = "Order ID Doesn't Exist"
    End If
```